# E-mailer script running each day (need some conceptual help)

Tags: php, mysql, math

I have a script that works in several steps to e-mail students at a school who are tardy.  The school essentially penalizes students who have 3 and 5 tardies. However, alongside that, there's a total tardy count.  For example, a student can have 16 tardies but their "penalizing" count will `16 % 5 === 1`.

This is how it works:

**A cron job runs at 3:00 each day checking the following:**
If the amount of times the student (`tardy % 5 == 3`), that means they have 3 tardies.  The script then updates a column called `tardyemail` for that particular student to equal 1.

If the amount of times the student is tardy % (mod) 5 = 0, that means they have 5 tardies. The script then updates the `tardyemail` column to equal 2.

Here's the relevant code:

```
if($row['times_tardy'] % 5 == 0) {
    echo $row['fname']." - 5<br />";
    $sql = "UPDATE student SET tardyemail = '2' WHERE rfid = '" . $row['StudentID'] . "'";
    mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
}
if($row['times_tardy'] % 5 == 3) {
    echo $row['fname']." - 3<br />";
    $sql = "UPDATE student SET tardyemail = '1' WHERE rfid = '" . $row['StudentID'] . "'";
    mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

**A separate cron script runs at 3:30 performing the following:**
Select students who's tardyemail column is equal to 1, and if it's equal to 1, send the template e-mail for 3 tardies out to those students. Then, update the tardyemail column to 0.

Select students who's tardyemail column is equal to 2, and if it's equal to 2, send the template e-mail for 5 tardies out to those students. Then, update the tardyemail column to 0.

Relevant code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE tardyemail = '1' AND grade_level > 10";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // send the email
    }
}
// update tardyemail to equal 0

$sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE tardyemail = '2' AND grade_level > 10";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         // sendthe mail
    } 
}
// update tardyemail to equal 0
```

The problem with this is the fact that, each day, student's at 3 or 5 tardies are continuously e-mailed because if they don't accrue any more tardies, they remain at 3 and 5.  I need some help figuring out a way to do this to not e-mail them multiple times if they haven't accrued any more tardies.

Comment: any reason its not done in the same script?

Comment: Not sure why I didn't do it in one script, but would that make a difference in this situation?

Comment: no it wouldn't ;)  In fact depending on the email work load separating them makes sense (it could be a slow/laborious process).

Answer (score 0):

Not only that, but -at least as you've described it- a student with 0 `times_tardy` will still pass the `%5=0` check (so they'll get the tardyemail type 2).

What you essentially need to do is determine what sort of emails to generate *when* you're storing the fact they've been tardy.  Additionally, although perhaps I don't understand your process, you probably want to send a tardyemail type 1 every time they're tardy after the first two times (eg the 4th time too) and a type 2 email every time they're tardy after the first four times (eg the 6th, 7th, 8th...nth times).  Your current plan gives students a benefit after they've hit 5 tardies (the next 2 are email free).

Rather than updating `times_tardy` blindly (at some point before hand?)  Why not set `tardyemail` to 1 or 2 based on the current value of `times_tardy` at the time you store the new tardy count.  Something like the following SQL statements:

```
-- First, Second Offence
UPDATE student SET times_tardy=times_tardy+1 
 WHERE times_tardy<2;
-- 3+ offence
UPDATE student SET times_tardy=times_tardy+1,tardyemail=1 
 WHERE times_tardy>=2 AND times_tardy<4;
-- 5+ offence
UPDATE student SET times_tardy=times_tardy+1,tardyemail=2 
 WHERE times_tardy>=4;
```

This assumes your times_tardy is stored in the same SQL table (you didn't say) but it could easily be modified in MySQL or PHP code if it's stored otherwise.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Times tardy is actually a count of all tardies stored in a table called attendance_main.  Additionally, it should only be mailing one template on every 3rd tardy, and the other template on every 5th tardy. Does your response still apply in this case?

Comment: Mostly, you need to determine what to email when you store the new tardy information... if you can't do that, then you'll have to check the `attendance_main` table by date to see who's newly tardy.

Answer (score 0):

Change the student.tardyemail column to a flag, student.tardyemail_sent.

When you update the student.times_tardy value, clear the flag (set tardyemail_sent = 0).

Then, to get students who should get the "3 times tardy" email,

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM student 
        WHERE times_tardy % 5 = 2
        AND tardyemail_sent = 0
        AND grade_level > 10";
```

(Note that you were using 3, which is off by one.)

To select students who should get the "5 times tardy" email,

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM student 
        WHERE times_tardy % 5 = 0
        AND times_tardy > 0
        AND tardyemail_sent = 0
        AND grade_level > 10";
```

(Note the extra clause to exclude those with 0 tardies.)

After sending the email, set tardyemail_sent = 1.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I'm looking for. times_tardy is actually a result of the following:

SELECT 
  attendance_main.StudentID, 
  student.first_name, student.grade_level,
  COUNT(DISTINCT date) AS `times_tardy`

How would I call the times_tardy column again if it's not actually a column?

Comment: Something like this (untested):


$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT attendance_main.date) AS times_tardy
            FROM student
            LEFT JOIN attendance_main ON attendance_main.StudentID = student.id
            GROUP BY student.id
        ) AS subselect
        WHERE times_tardy % 5 = 2
        AND tardyemail_sent = 0
        AND grade_level > 10";

This is computationally intensive, though. Probably better off storing the computed value in a new column, student.times_tardy.